# Can we enable Knowledge Users on Profiles or is it only User based?

Tags: permissions, knowledge

I have created a few `knowledge Article` and I have given the following permissions to the Support Manager profile. In that profile I have many managers (say 50). Do I need to enable knowledge User for all the 50 managers or is there any ways to that at profile level?

```
Manage Knowledge Article Import/Export   
Manage Articles  
Manage Salesforce Knowledge  
Allow View Knowledge     
Knowledge One
```

[image]

I know that Unless we don't enable the "Knowledge User", manager wont be able to see the "Knowledge" and "Article Management" tab.

Answer (score 0):

If I correct understand you:

You must add to all of them permission in user settings ( Setup -> User -> your manager) and again, again.

[image]

Or you try use Data Loader

[Data Loader - mass update](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000199705&type=1)